# ZEND + MAC + MYSQL = ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, macos, zend-framework

It seems to me that apparently everyone has their own version of this problem, but I'll try and ask anyway.

When I'm starting mysql trough Terminal with `/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.server start`

it returns

`. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/zend/mysql/data/imac-j.gateway.2wire.net.pid).`

It was working fine yesterday I really don't know what happens. Im just starting learning mysql it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`sudo /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.server start`

Comment: It's working now but I just installed it again, man, I really don't know what happened, I'll try your line if it happens again, thank you